# Is there a way to populate a dataGridView from multiple lists without iterating through the lists?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say I have three lists containing multiple objects.  Lets also assume they each contain the same number of items.  For example

```
Dim mylist1 as List(Of Integer)
Dim myList2 as List(Of Integer)
Dim myList3 as List(Of Integer)
...
... <lists are populated here with say 10 items each
...
```

Now say I have a dataGridView that I have defined as having three columns.  Is there a way to assign the contents of each of the lists to each of the three columns (e.g. column 1 = myList1, column 2 = myList2, etc.) without iterating through each of the lists?  I know I could define a dataTable, create the columns, and iterate through each of the lists...then associate the dataTable to the dataGridView's dataSource.  However, I don't want to iterate through the lists since in my real application, these lists are large and the iteration would take too long.  I'm just wondering how to assign these lists to a column in a dataTable in bulk.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I guess I know how to bind a dataTable to a dataGridView using the DataSource property.  However, the question is, how do I load the three lists into each column of the dataTable?

Answer (score 1):

Use VirtualMode.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private mlst1 As New List(Of Integer)
  Private mlst2 As New List(Of Integer)
  Private mlst3 As New List(Of Integer)


  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    mlst1.Add(1)
    mlst1.Add(2)
    mlst1.Add(3)

    mlst2.Add(4)
    mlst2.Add(5)
    mlst2.Add(6)

    mlst3.Add(7)
    mlst3.Add(8)
    mlst3.Add(9)

    DataGridView1.VirtualMode = True
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("A", "A")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("B", "B")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("C", "C")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
  End Sub


  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueNeeded
    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
      Case 0
        e.Value = mlst1(e.RowIndex)
      Case 1
        e.Value = mlst2(e.RowIndex)
      Case 2
        e.Value = mlst3(e.RowIndex)
      Case Else
        e.Value = ""
    End Select
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This seems awfully complex given that it seems like the _CellValueNeeded event is not the only event that needs to be handled.  I was doing some research and there are a whole series of events that have to be checked for.   In addition, when using just the _CellValueNeeded, I get an error saying I need to add the gridView using "WithEvents" modifier.  Tried doing that but couldn't get it to work.  It's amazing there is no easier way to simply take a list and bind it to a column in a dataTable or dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use the `.Zip` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` to associate your three lists together.

C#

```
var output
    = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b })
           .Zip(list3, (x, c) => new { First = x.a, Second = x.b, Third = c });
```

VB

```
Dim output 
     = list1.Zip(list2, function (a, b) new With { .a = a, .b = b }) _
            .Zip(list3, function (x, c) new with { .First = x.a, .Second = x.b, .Third = c })
```

This will result in a sequence of anonymous typed objects, having the properties `First, Second, Third`. The iteration of the lists will be deferred until needed, which would be at the point you bind the data to your control.